# How to listen event when we fire in angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have fired an event in one function of my typescript file like `this.loaderLoader.emit(true)` Now i want to listen this in other component how can i do that?

Comment: What is this event? It's an `@Output`? If so, you can only catch this event fired in his parent component

Comment: if you're using a parent-child relationship, you use [`@Output`](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component), if has no parent-child relationship you should use a service.

Answer (score 2):

if you have an eventemitter like this in your component:

```
@Output('loaderLoader') loaderLoader: EventEmitter<boolean>;
```

and you fire it with

```
this.loaderLoader.emit(true);
```

you can listen to it an a parent component with an event binding

```
<component-name (loaderLaoder)="handlerMethod($event)">
```